# FreeRtos calling vTaskDelete from IRQ

Tags: task, freertos, irq

I spent some time but I can't find any info if it's allowed to call vTaskDelete from IRQ handler? I know some methods have specialized version for usage in IRQ routines however I can't find anything related to vTaskDelete. Currently it works but I don't want to do some hard to discover bug just because I didn't found info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling a callback from the IRQ then it is still in the IRQ context.  Calling [vTaskDelete()](https://www.freertos.org/a00126.html) with a NULL parameter would delete the task that was running before the interrupt was entered, so the interrupt would then try to return to a task that was no longer running.  Even if that were not the case then the rule of thumb is not to use API functions that do not end in "FromISR" from an interrupt (the separate API ensures fewer decision points in the function, faster and standard interrupt entry as it doesn't need to keep an interrupt nesting variable, no need to pass parameters that don't make sense in an interrupt context [like a block time] into an interrupt function, etc.).

Comment: Not sure why you assume I call vTaskDelete with NULL, but ok, this is not a problem. You pointed what I suspected that method which can be called from IRQ should have suffix FromISR. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not calling vTaskDelete with a NULL argument because there is no current task when you are in interrupt context. In any case vTaskDelete() should not be called from interrupt context. For example, it's implementation will call vPortFree() to free the TCB of the task.

Comment: I'm calling callback from IRQ in this callback is vTaskDelete(taskHandle) where taskHandle is a static variable.